# Erro 404 ao carregar recursos da pasta node_modules com o Angular2

Tags: angular

Estou com uma aplicação usando angular 4 que está dando erro 404 ao tentar carregar recursos *css*, fontes e javascript da pasta *node_modules*.

Está assim em meu index.html:

```
<link href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" />
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css" />
```

Meu angular-cli está atualizado e antes eu carregava normalmente.

Do que andei procurando, li que precisava da configuração `"moduleResolution": "node"` no tsconfig.json. Já estava lá e não está funcionando.

O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Para inserir bibliotecas de terceiros como *font awesome* e *bootstrap* você deve modificar seu arquivo `.angular-cli.json` no seu projeto para quando for feito o **build** do projeto os arquivos sejam incluídos.

```
    "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css"
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
```

no seu caso adicione apenas no campo de `style` os caminhos dos arquivos **css** necessarios para o projeto, e remova eles do `index.html` para deixar a cargo do angular inserir esses arquivos.